# Automatic 12V plant watering system?

Tags: dc-motor, 12v, detector

I'm planning to make a plant watering system . There is a beeper so it will alert us when the soil is dry.I have got a 12V DC motor . So i'll be removing this beeper and i need to add this DC motor.What all change are needed to made in the circuit so as to make this automatic.I can use my Laptop Adapter as the power source. This circuit was taken from internet . I had actually made this one with the 12v DC motor back in 2012 with the help of a Electronic Engineer.He actually added a small circuit at the end of this circuit  without actually making a big change to the rest of the circuit.I had lost that modified circuit .There were two power sources with that working circuit one from the Batteries and other from the Mains via 12v adapter.

[image: Circuit]

List of  items in the circuit.

R1,R4 : 470K   1/4W Resistors
R2 : 47K   1/2W Trimmer Cermet or Carbon
R3 : 100K   1/4W Resistor
R5 : 3K3  1/4W Resistor
R6 : 15K   1/4W Resistor
R7 : 100R   1/4W Resistor

C1 : 1nF  63V Polyester Capacitor
C2 : 330nF  63V Polyester Capacitor
C3,C4 : 10µF  25V Electrolytic Capacitors

D1 : 1N4148  75V 150mA Diode
Beeper : 3V

IC1 : 4093  Quad 2 input Schmitt NAND Gate IC

Q1 : BC557  45V 100mA PNP Transistor

P1,P2 : Probes  (See Notes)

B1 : 3V  Battery (2xAA, N or AAA 1.5V Cells in series)

Comment: Hiya manutd, is the circuit you have provided proven? if so, the trigger will work the same way and all you will need to do is adjust the driver for the load (in this case the beeper) to suit the motor.  the exact details will depend on the motor.  Am I right in thinking that the motor you're talking about is a water pump?

Comment: @GipsyDanger It's a 12V DC Water Pump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(EDITED) - Notice that the last Nand gate ahead of the beeper looks to be a slow oscillator, (the beeper likely rings as ON-OFF-ON-OFF....). The input to the last Nand changes from being either a low signal or a fast square wave signal, (which corresponds to wet soil then to dry soil conditions).

The diode in the feedback of the last Nand actually makes things a bit more complicated as it has an uneven charge/discharge affect on C3.  The result is that the last Nand outputs a gated burst of the square wave pulses at a low duty cycle when the soil is dry (giving a Beep-Beep-Beeping).  Then when the soil is wet the output is just a high, which keeps Q1 turned off (and noda Beeping).

Since the active signal is a bunch of fast pulses it would be best to converted this into a simple DC voltage or a single pulse that can easily drive a DC motor, (or a relay coil).  One solution would be to create a small AC-DC converter then use this as the input for a motor driver.

The circuit below can take a continuous stream of pulses or a quick burst of pulses and convert it into a DC voltage or a single DC pulse for driving a DC motor.

The NPN and diodes are not critical, (2N3904 transistor and 1N4001 diodes would suffice). Q1 takes the 3v pulses and converts them to 12v pulses, they are then passed as AC and rectified by C1-D1-D2. The rectified DC builds up on C2 and turns on Q3 which controls the motor.  R3 discharges C2 after the AC input stops.  Increasing the value of R3 could extend the width of a DC pulse if needed, (for example if input was taken from the beeper top end).  D3 shorts out any spikes from the motor switching and C4 helps reduces motor noise on the +12v line.  The NMOS part would need to be selected to safely pass the maximum current of the DC motor.

The "INPUT" for this circuit could be from any of the points with the AC (water me) signal, for example: Nand gate pins 3-5, or Nand pins 1-2-10, or even the beeper high end (above the resistor) if short DC pulses into the motor are acceptable.  In this later case the motor would run only for the short time the beeper normally sounded.

As before, you may want to keep the beeper in the circuit for testing and for a warning in case the watering jams on for any reason.  A nice effect of using an AC-DC converter circuit like this is that if the input were to jam high or a low the output will not turn on the motor.

[image: circuit]

Comment: @Tut, yes, you are correct.  Missed that first Nand osc.  Seems I need an edit.

Comment: Edit complete...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the beeper, find a relay that has a coil compatible with the circuit's power supply and use the coil contacts for activating a motor running from 12V. If the circuit you have shown operates from 12V then it can be easier - use a P channel power mosfet instead of the BJT (Q1).

All this assumes that the circuit you have posted does what you want it to functionally.

Comment: Kinda nasty looking switching action there.. I think there's going to be a bunch of kHz cycles at the output before it turns 'on' more-or-less continuously. No problem for a beeper but the relay contacts might not close cleanly.